# Loading the data to android spinner and it crashes when selecting an item

Tags: android, android-spinner

I have this method and and it returns three values as shown in the screenshot below,

```
List<String> resultSizes = getFilteredSizes(crustSelectedItem);
```

[image]

And I'm loading these 3 data to android spinner, then I'm using this code of piece to get the spinner value I have selected,

```
String StrSizeSPPosition = String.valueOf(sizeSP.getSelectedItemPosition());
```

it says `0`.

Then I have a string list as `sizePrice`,
and it returns the below shown values,

[image]

Im using this piece of code to get the selected item's respected value using this,

```
StrPriceSize = sizePrice.get(SizeSPPosition); // crashes here
PriceSize = Double.parseDouble(StrPriceSize);
System.out.println("PriceSize = " + PriceSize);
```

My problem is when I select pan large then it should give the output as 1560 because the I'm getting the index positions, but it gives 450. and when I select other value it crashes giving an exception.

this is the exception,

[image]

this is the logcat output

[image]

Complete code

```
                        List<String> resultSizes = getFilteredSizes(crustSelectedItem);

                        ArrayAdapter<String> dataAdapterDes = new ArrayAdapter<String>(
                                Activity.this,
                                android.R.layout.simple_spinner_item,
                                resultSizes);
                        dataAdapterDes
                                .setDropDownViewResource(android.R.layout.simple_spinner_dropdown_item);
                        sizeSP.setAdapter(dataAdapterDes);

                        sizeSP.setOnItemSelectedListener(new MyOnItemSelectedListener(
                                Activity.this) {

                            public void onNothingSelected(AdapterView<?> arg0) {
                            }

                            @Override
                            public void onItemSelected(AdapterView<?> parent,
                                    View view, int position, long id) {

                                String sizeSelectedItem = sizeSP
                                        .getSelectedItem().toString();

                                String StrSizeSPPosition = String
                                        .valueOf(sizeSP
                                                .getSelectedItemPosition());

                                System.out.println("sizeSelectedItem = "
                                        + sizeSelectedItem);
                                System.out.println("StrSizeSPPosition = "
                                        + StrSizeSPPosition);

                                SizeSPPosition = Integer
                                        .parseInt(StrSizeSPPosition);

                                String StrPriceSize = sizePrice
                                        .get(SizeSPPosition);
                                PriceSize = Double.parseDouble(StrPriceSize);
```

(I have another option it has only 1 value when I'm selecting that it work properly without crashing, i think I'm getting this issue only when I have data mora that 1)
I hope my question is clear enough to understand. If you need more details please ask to make the question clear. Any help would be appreciated to sort out this.

Comment: show code, not only debug pupups

Comment: if using `StrPriceSize = resultSizes.get(SizeSPPosition);` then? because in posted image 1560,870,450 is showing in `resultSizes` List

Comment: @ρяσѕρєя K then taking the price and display (PriceSize) it. what I'm trying to do is, use the selected item position and get the price of the item from the price array(sizePrice) using the selected item position.

Comment: @Piotr Golinski i have updated the code

Comment: @ρяσѕρєя K I was using the same method to get all the prices in order to get a screen shot thats y resultSizes is there in that screen shot. Actrually it should be sizePrice

Comment: You are using `SizeSPPosition` to get position but you are storing position/index value in `StrSizeSPPosition`. Please post the code where you are storing position values `SizeSPPosition`

Comment: String StrSizeSPPosition = String.valueOf(sizeSP.getSelectedItemPosition()); I have this code. then I'm converting String StrSizeSPPosition into int SizeSPPosition value. thats all what I do

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Instead of this line of code :-

```
String StrPriceSize = sizePrice.get(SizeSPPosition);
PriceSize = Double.parseDouble(StrPriceSize);
```

Put this code:-

```
String StrPriceSize = resultSizes.get(SizeSPPosition);
 PriceSize = Double.parseDouble(StrPriceSize);
```

or try this:-

try to print Log.d("sizePriceList", sizePrice+""); in the code and check how many elements you are getting when selecting item from spinner. your logcat showing an exception of indexoutofbound that means you are getting only one item in sizePrice

Comment: my bad I'm using the same method to get the output because I wanted to take a screenshot. That method is original used to get the resultSizes not the prices. sizePrice is string list where I'm addding all the prices

Comment: it doesn't solve, i think you have misunderstoond the sizePrice and resultSizes because of my screen shot

Comment: i have answered by looking your code and screen shots obviously the answer i have given is correct by looking your code and screen shot. please post proper code and screen shot so anybody can help you in right way

Comment: check my screen shot, i have edited something, still u believe ur answer is correct?

Comment: I am not saying my answer is perfect and correct i think the problem you are getting is because of sizePrice variable.

Comment: try to print `Log.d("sizePriceList", sizePrice+"");` in the code and check how many elements you are getting when selecting item from spinner. your logcat showing an exception of `indexoutofbound` that means you are getting only one item in `sizePrice `

Comment: This gave only 1 output, then I have initialized arraylist inside the for loop that was the issue. that your comment was really helpful. Should i up vote ur complete answer?